# I have a column of alphanumeric data and would like to sum the values that are one row below the lookup value

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, sum, match

I would like to return the sum of all values that are directly below a look up value "Pre173RB" in a single column.
[image]

First I used index and match but this is limited to only finding the first value "8".

=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(E1,B:B,0)+1,1)

I then attempted to incorporate the above formula into the repeating sequence below.  The formula returned the first value in the column "30".  The desired return is "18".

=INDEX(B:B, SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(E$1,B:B,0)+1), MATCH(ROW(B:B), ROW(B:B)), ""),ROWS(A$1:A1)))

I've attempted to use sumif in the above formula as well but errors return.

Any assistance is appreciated.  I am probably complicating the formula.

Answer (score 1):

`=SUMIFS(B2:B26,B1:B25,E1)`

Note that the sum range is offset one row versus the condition range.

Comment: If you were to stick with INDEX a combination of INDEX/AGGREGATE(SUM) would be something to look into

Comment: Correct, that was a typo. Edited it.